# Logout from website doesn't perform while running Selenium tests using profile with chromedriver 115+

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We have the following Selenium test case:

1. create new driver instance before each execution
2. login to web application
3. execute steps from the scenario
4. log out from web application

do steps 1-4 for 10 times.

When I run test case on the latest Chrome and with using User Profile (on dirty cache), I have the issue, that sometimes after navigating to the web page, User is already logged into applications, despite logging out before

Also we have noticed that there is 'Restore Pages' dialog appears after opening Chrome (after 2d and further runs)
[image]

After logout we perform driver.Quit() and driver.Dispose(). And there are no chromedriver.exe or chrome.exe processes after performing Quit() and Dispose().

Some data:

- Error appeared with ChromeDriver version **115.0.5790.10200**.
- It wasn't reproduced with ChromeDriver 114 and Chrome 115.
- After updating Chrome to the version 116 and driver to the version 116.0.5845.9600 issues is still reproducible.
- Issue is not reproduced without User Profile (on clean cache).

If add Thread.Sleep(30 sec) there is still 'Restore Pages' dialog after login, but issues is not reproduced, user is not logged into the application after logout. But if use less timeout, for example 5/10/20 seconds - we catch the error.

It was a suggestion to do the following: "For the restore page problem I think that if you do driver.close() 2-3 second pause then driver.quit() it will solve the problem it's worked for me but I'm not sure if it works for you. And I'm not sure if it will fix your disconnection problem" - Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.